# Password not accepting

Tags: installation, password, thunderbird, mozilla

I wrote my password down when I installed Ubuntu. Now I enter that password, careful to note uppercase and lowercase and numerals. But it will not accept, as I am attempting to install Thunderbird.

What can I do?

Comment: So you are still logged in and the prompt wont accept the password. Or you can log out and in, but not install?

Answer (score 0):

First I would try resetting the password, maybe careful was just not careful enough :)
You can reset the password using the method described in the following [link](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword)

If that won't solve your problem it is indeed important to now if you can use your password for logging in (or do you use autologin?).